# Best Approach to edit my model class in seperate stages, inside my asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 order management system. Where I have the following Order model class:-

```
    public partial class SOrder
        {
    //Stage 1
            public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
            public int CustomerID { get; set; }
            public int OrderStatusID { get; set; }
            public int OrderTypeID { get; set; }
            public int CommissionTypeID { get; set; }
            public string QuoteNumber { get; set; }
            public string ServiceName { get; set; }
            public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
    //stage 2
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public string AssetID { get; set; }
    //stage3
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> LiveDate { get; set; }
            public int ContractLength { get; set; }
   //system generated     
        public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public int StageNumber { get; set; }
   //code goes here 
        public virtual OrderStatu OrderStatu { get; set; }
        public virtual OrderType OrderType { get; set; }

        }
```

Now I want to allow editing the model in 5 separate stages. Where each stage will be handled by separate group of users.
Current I am following this approach, where inside my view I am checking the stage number and hide the related fields accordingly:-

```
@model S.Models.SOrder
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Order";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.OrderID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.StageNumber)
    <div >
    <span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerID)</span> 

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Customers, "Choose...") 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID)
   <br />
    <span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientManagerID)</span> 


 //code goes here..   

     if (Model!=null && Model.StageNumber >= 2)
    {
            <div>
    <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetID) </span> 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetID) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetID)
</div>
    .....
    }
```

And here is how my Post edit action method looks like:-

```
         [HttpPost]

         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
         public ActionResult Edit(SOrder sorder)
         {

             try
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {
                     var dborder = repository.getOrder(sorder.OrderID);
                     repository.DetachedOrder(dborder);
                     sorder.OrderNumber = dborder.OrderNumber;

                     sorder.Created = dborder.Created;


                     sorder.StageNumber = tmsorder.StageNumber+1;
                     //code goes here.
```

But I am facing these issues:-

1. Currently unauthorized user or hackers can pass the fields which is not showing inside the view, by using tools such as fiddler. So is there a way to handle this logic inside the Post Edit action method? So I can force users to only edit the related field at each stage?
2. I am thinking of another approach to handle my logic. By using 5 view model classes, one model class for each stage, instead of one model class at all the stages as I am currently doing. But when I start doing so I realized that I need to have 5 different Post edit action methods. Because each edit action method should accept the related model class. So not sure if I can benefit from view models to implement my stages?
3. Is there any other approach I can follow, to allow modifying my model class in stages?
   Thanks

Comment: 5 view models will be required, especially if you want any kind of validation  on any of your properties. But you can always have a parent view model containing 5 properties for each 'stage' and a value indicating the current stage if you want only one POST method (only one of the 5 properties will be populated and the other 4 will be `null`). But since each stage would need to be saved separately there would be no real advantage in having only one POST method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your reply .. so are you saying that i need to have 5 view models and 5 post edit action methods ? but is there a way to have only one Post edit action method..and can you provide some general code sample ..

Comment: As I noted in the first comment, you could have 1 view model containing 5 view models - `public Stage1VM Stage1 { get; set; }`, `public Stage2VM Stage2 { get; set; }` etc and post that back to one POST method, but I do not see any advantage in doing that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but how i can only bind the related fields at the Post edit action method at each stage? so that users at stage 1 can not pass stage 2 fields ????usually i define the Bind list at the action method level .. not sure if i can have different Bind list based on the stage number inside the same Post action method ?

Comment: Because if your editing stage 2, you only save the values that are in the `Stage2VM Stage2` property. But this approach will mean you cannot apply validation to your properties if you storing this all in one table. Surely a better approach would be to have 5 database tables with 1-1 relationships (which will also allow you to store the `ModifiedBy` fields etc. for each stage)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but if i have separate Db tables ,, then it will be difficult to modify my stages fields in the future,, i am searching for a more dynamic approach ..

Comment: @StephenMuecke so you are saying to create 5 separate DB tables,, then 5 separate Post action methods and 5 separate views.. seems in this case i will have very static design .. so if our users need to add extra field or merge steps then it will be hard to apply these changes...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111811/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-john-g).